# Should I use getHours() or getUTCHours for my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the time on the computer of the person who is accessing my website.  Should I use getHours() or getUTCHours()?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short answer is it depends.  If you want the hours as it displays on a clock for their timezone you will want getHours() as it returns the hours in their local time.  If you want the hours in Universal Time (no timezone adjustment) then use getUTCHours()

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend `getUTCHours` - keeping everything in UTC removes a lot of headaches when it comes to working with dates and times.

Comment: I really suffered on that, great advice.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you're using it for. If you want to get the user's local time, use `getHours()`. If you want to get something like a time offset (say, "hours until the new CoD is released in the UK"), use `getUTCHours()` as an absolute reference point. Bear in mind, however, that if the user's clock is set wrong, `getUTC*()` functions will return times that aren't really UTC - all they do really is remove the `getGMTOffset()` amount for you.

Answer (score 2):

`getHours` will return the time according to their timezone, `getUTCHours` will get their time converted to UTC. Would probably be easier to use `getUTCHours` so everyone is returning their time in the same timezone.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do, but i'd agree with Andrew, if you use getUTC*** it becomes easier for you to handle dates and times